# How to change vba Declaration statement to be compatible with Windows 64 bit

Tags: vba, 32bit-64bit

I have a model that previously only was used by people with 32 bit Windows, but now users are being upgraded to 64 bit and I need to make the declaration statement below compatible for both systems:

```
'Import functions from external DLL's
Public Declare Function SendMailWithAttachments Lib "PostSMTP.xll" ( _
                       ByVal strServer As String, _
                       ByVal uPort As Integer, _
                       ByVal strFrom As String, _
                       ByVal strTo As String, _
                       ByVal strSubject As String, _
                       ByVal strBody As String, _
                       ByVal strAttachments As String) As Integer
```

I tried including PtrSafe in the code but that still did not work. This is the first time I've had to make a change like this so I'm not sure where to start. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: please [format code as code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thank you for reformatting...rookie mistake as this is my first time posting a question...

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes, when the user with 64 bit runs it, the error is the file ("PostSMTP.xll") could not be found. Regardless if PtrSafe is included.

Comment: PtrSafe is only one part of it.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, there are 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Windows. You may or may not also know that there are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of MS Office. What you (and your IT staff) have probably missed is that [**Microsoft strongly recommends the 32-bit version of Office for most users, even when running 64-bit Windows.**](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/enterprise/356173/microsoft-warns-users-off-64-bit-office-2010)

This is one of the reasons why.

Thankfully, that article was written for Office 2010. While most of the things in it are still true for Office 2013, and the general recommendation remains, you can now at least now fix your `DECLARE` statements to work with 64-bit Office if you have to. Here's the MSDN article that covers how to do it:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx

You've already seen one part of it, but PtrSafe is not the whole story. It also involves using the right pointer type in the right scenario. Additionally, you're using an `xll` file, which was itself written using VBA. *You must also modify the original file to also correctly use PtrSafe and the right `LongPtr` type.* If you are unable to do this, the 32-bit version of Office is your only option.

Comment: thanks that was very informative. For now I was able to get IT to roll back to 32 bit version while I work on getting the original xll updated.

Answer (score -1):

use PtrSafe in your Function Declaration
like:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function
```